# MixedLMResults object return NaN BIC. What can be the reason?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, panel-data, random-effects

Here is my code:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
md = smf.mixedlm("dep ~ indep", df, groups=df["groups"], re_formula='~indep')
mdf = md.fit(method=["lbfgs"])
```

mdf.bic returns nan as output. What can be the reason? If it is package related problem. Could anyone provide manual calculation of BIC for this case?

Comment: you cannot determine the degree of freedom, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23778/how-should-mixed-effects-models-be-compared-and-or-validated, hence in the package, I guess the author is right not to provide the bic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the comment below your question from @StupidWolf, I think it's correct that BIC is not provided for LM models. Even when you print `mdf.summary()`, you will find neither BIC nor AIC in the output.

But if you want to calculate BIC, the formula is quite simple. You can even refer to the code in `statsmodels`:

```py
def bic(self):
    """Bayesian information criterion"""
    if self.reml:
        return np.nan
    if self.freepat is not None:
        df = self.freepat.get_packed(use_sqrt=False, has_fe=True).sum() + 1
    else:
        df = self.params.size + 1
    return -2 * self.llf + np.log(self.nobs) * df
```

This should answer your question:

- `self.reml` (REstricted Maximum Likelihood) is set to true - that's the reason why are you getting `nan` for BIC.
- it shows you, how to calculate BIC

You can see that BIC calculation follow a standard BIC formula. It takes logarithms of number of data points/observations multiplied by number of free parameters/degree of freedom (`np.log(self.nobs) * df`) and subtract Log-likelihood of model times 2 (`-2 * self.llf`). So, you could calculate BIC with your code as follows:

```py
-2 * mdf.llf + np.log(mdf.nobs) * (mdf.df_modelwc)
```

Note, that here I used `mdf.df_modelwc` which in fact, in this case, returns `mdf.params.size`.

But beware of the things mentioned in the beginning (for completeness, here is the link to SE provided by @StupidWolf - [How should mixed effects models be compared and or validated?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/23964/231628).